# Word for delaying a decision with only one option?

Tags: single-word-requests

Can anyone tell me a **single** word that describes delaying a decision, although there is only one option?

Comment: That combines so many concepts that you're only going to find a single word for it in agglutinative languages.

Comment: If there's only one option, I don't really think "decision" can be the action. We're probably looking at something more like *acquiescence* or *acknowledgement*. Or maybe [micawberism](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Micawberism) - putting off acceptance of the poor choice on offer right now in the expectation that something better will turn up.

Comment: ...on a Thursday?

Comment: Is it a decision if there's *really* just a single option? If there is *no way* to do anything but that option, then it's not a decision, is it?

Comment: *Dilly-dallying?*

Comment: I'm not there's a single word that conveys this complex a concept. The first thing that came to my mind is "delaying the inevitable" - but most single words I can think of are just synonyms for "delaying," without any particular association with a decision-that's-not-a-decision.

Comment: Thanks all for your efforts.  A colleague is convinced that such a word exists (I'm not, for the record) so thought I'd ask those better placed than me to prove/disprove.  Temporise seems the closest (colleague says not the word he can't remember).  For what it's worth, don't think Micawberism fits the bill @FumbleFingers, this being akin to 'over-optimism'?

Comment: @Enell: Well I'm aware that *temporise* can mean *putting off making a decision*, but I don't see how you can put off a decision if you already know what you have decided/will decide. And *micawberism* doesn't necessarily imply *overoptimistic* - something always *did* turn up for Micawber!

Comment: When a board of directors does this the say the decision has been tabled.

Answer (score 7):

If there is only one course of action, then there is not really a decision to make, so this is a case of

- [delaying](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/delay?q=delaying)

  > Postpone or defer (an action)
- [stalling](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/stall?q=stall)

  > Stop or cause to stop making progress
- [procrastinating](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/procrastinate?q=procrastinate)

  > Delay or postpone action; put off doing something
- [dragging one's feet/heels](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/drag?q=drag+your+heels#drag__48)

  > Be deliberately slow or reluctant to act
- [deferring](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/defer?q=defer)

  > Put off (an action or event) to a later time; postpone

If there's a chance that the situation will change between now and when action can no longer be avoided, you might say

- [hedging](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hedge?q=hedge)

> protecting oneself against financial loss or other adverse circumstances
>   
>   -- All definitions from Oxford Dictionaries Online

Comment: +1 for *hedging* (**if** there's a chance...)

Answer (score 5):

If you want a word with a bit of color to it, you might try *filibustering* or *stonewalling*.

Those both include the additional notion of blocking something, not just of avoiding it, which seems to be what the OP is requesting.

Other verbs besides those previously mentioned in other answers include *dawdle, bide,* and *tarry*.

However, there is no sense of inevitability here, or of something that has no other possible course of action. I’m not sure it makes sense to have a word for avoiding a “decision” with only one “option”. It doesn’t seem like much of a decision if there is no choice involved, nor can something be an option if there is but one of them.

It’s a bit like trying to avoid death or taxes: sure, you might be able to file for an extension, but these things only go so far.  :)

Comment: [Mr. Smith goes to Washington](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0031679/)++

Answer (score 3):

I think to procrastinate implies laziness, avoiding a duty, and that's not really the sense I got from the question. In my mind, the best way to express the idea asked for is with the phrase 'to delay the inevitable'.

If forced to express this idea in a single word (though I don't know why that would be the case - a strict word limit?), I'd probably opt for  the verb **to temporize**: to behave indecisively or evasively in order to to delay acting.

Answer (score 3):

The word you want is **stalling**.

Answer (score 2):

The word that immediately came to my mind was [*procrastination*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/procrastination).

Comment: Except that that doesn't capture the decision-taking or the but-it's-not-really-a-decision aspects.

Answer (score 1):

Could this be a case of **over-analysing** (over-analyzing in Americaneze)? Or (similar) overthinking?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds less like indecisiveness and more like 'fear of moving forward' so I would offer:

- dither
- hem and haw
- drag your feet

Answer (score 0):

A typical phrase is "*You're **avoiding the inevitable***".